# Wrong answer from getAttribute only in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript

I have a site that shows slips. The user can change the month to get the relevant slip.
In the begining they get the last slip. For the first time when they change the month they get the right slip. After this they still get the first slip; it does not matter what they choose.

The problem is only in chrome and IE.

My function is:

```
function submitform2() {    
    var v = document.getElementById("SlipSelectorControl1_ddlSlipMonths").value;
    if (v < 10) {
        v = "0" + v;
    }
    var w;
    w = document.getElementById("SlipSelectorControl1_txtEmployeeID").getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("txtEmployeeID1").setAttribute("value",w);
    document.getElementById("hiddenEmplyID1").setAttribute("value", w);


    w = document.getElementById("SlipSelectorControl1_ddlSlipMonths")[1].getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("ddlSlipMonths1").setAttribute("value", w);

    w = document.getElementById("SlipSelectorControl1_ddlSlipYears")[0].getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("ddlSlipYears1").setAttribute("value",w);
    document.getElementById("hiddenMonthText1").setAttribute("value", w + v);


    w = document.getElementById("SlipSelectorControl1_ddlOffice")[0].getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("ddlOffice1").setAttribute("value",w);
    document.getElementById("hiddenOffice1").setAttribute("value",w);
    document.forms[2].action  = "Slip.aspx" ;
    document.forms[2].method="post";
    document.forms[2].target = "slip";
    document.forms[2].submit(); 
}
```

Comment: If those elements are `<input>` elements, you don't have to use `.getAttribute()` or `setAttribute()` at all. Just access/set the `value` property directly on the objects.

Comment: Please give a little more effort in asking the question if you want a proper response, out of respect. There's no spelling/grammar/punctuation checking at all in this post, others will find it hard to reuse this information

Comment: can you give me one example? thanks

Comment: @AndrueAnderson English is not my mother tongue. i'm sorry.

Comment: @uriel which is why I suggested more effort rather than not posting

Comment: What is `SlipSelectorControl1_ddlSlipMonths`? What value is wrong?

Comment: @epascarello i get the first choice even i changed it.

Comment: Please answer this: **What type of element is SlipSelectorControl1_ddlSlipMonths?** Why are you using getAttribute/setAttribute to read/set a value?

Comment: The value attribute is only used to set the initial value of an input. This attribute is not reflected in the DOM upon value changes. You must use the value property of the element object to get the most recent value.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace thanks you